# How do I add a dot in a specific spot in a filename?

Tags: linux, filenames

I want to add a dot in a filename such as from this:

190428_Li_00000063.fits

It becomes this:

190428_Li_.00000063.fits

I need to do this for a bunch of files that all start with the prefix 190428_Li_ but have different numbers in the end.

This is what I tried:

```html
from pathlib import Path
directory = '/net/virgo01/data/users/costa/MYPROJECT/'
path = Path(directory)
for filepath in path.iterdir():
    if filepath.suffix.lower() in ['.fits', '.fit', '.fts']:
        filepaths.append(filepath)
part1 = []
part2 = []
part3 = []
for filepath in filepaths:
    part1 = filepath.split('i_')
    part2 = part1[0].append('i_.')
    part3 = part2.append(part1[-1])
```

Comment: **Show us what you’ve done so far** so that we have something to start with. It’s much easier for us to help you with existing code, and people are far more likely to help when they don’t have to start from zero with "How do I do this?"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.